# Performance issues on ASP.NET MVC 2 with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, asp.net-mvc-2, jmeter

*EDIT: I think it's a problem on the subquery on the LINQ-generated query, it get all the records... But I don't know how could I fix it*

I have made a simple ASP.NET MVC 2 application that does SELECT queries on a view, I get really poor performance, and while doing a simple benchmark with jMeter (10 conccurents connection) while disabling the cache (I don't want everything to rely on the non customizable/extreme OutputCache)

I see that the SQL Server get overloaded, consuming a LOT of CPU (up to 100%) and all its reserved memory space (512MB)

Here is the action code that cause the problems (manual transactions because it cause DeadLock with the other program that insert new data on the database) :

```
public ActionResult Index(int page = 0)
{
    IronViperEntities db = new IronViperEntities();
    db.Connection.Open();
    DbTransaction transaction = db.Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
    var messages = (from globalView in db.GlobalViews orderby globalView.MessagePostDate descending select globalView).Skip(page*perPage).Take(perPage);
    transaction.Commit();
    db.Connection.Close();
    ViewData["page"] = page;
    ViewData["messages"] = messages;
    return View();
}
```

Here is the query executed on the database :

```
SELECT TOP (100) 
[Extent1].[MessageId] AS [MessageId], 
[Extent1].[MessageUuid] AS [MessageUuid], 
[Extent1].[MessageData] AS [MessageData], 
[Extent1].[MessagePostDate] AS [MessagePostDate], 
[Extent1].[ChannelName] AS [ChannelName], 
[Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
[Extent1].[UserUuid] AS [UserUuid], 
[Extent1].[ChannelUuid] AS [ChannelUuid]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[MessageId] AS [MessageId], [Extent1].[MessageUuid] AS [MessageUuid], [Extent1].[MessageData] AS [MessageData], [Extent1].[MessagePostDate] AS [MessagePostDate], [Extent1].[ChannelName] AS [ChannelName], [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], [Extent1].[UserUuid] AS [UserUuid], [Extent1].[ChannelUuid] AS [ChannelUuid], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[MessagePostDate] DESC) AS [row_number]
    FROM (SELECT 
      [GlobalView].[MessageId] AS [MessageId], 
      [GlobalView].[MessageUuid] AS [MessageUuid], 
      [GlobalView].[MessageData] AS [MessageData], 
      [GlobalView].[MessagePostDate] AS [MessagePostDate], 
      [GlobalView].[ChannelName] AS [ChannelName], 
      [GlobalView].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
      [GlobalView].[UserUuid] AS [UserUuid], 
      [GlobalView].[ChannelUuid] AS [ChannelUuid]
      FROM [dbo].[GlobalView] AS [GlobalView]) AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Extent1].[MessagePostDate] DESC
```

View Code :

```
SELECT     dbo.Messages.Id AS MessageId, dbo.Messages.Uuid AS MessageUuid, dbo.Messages.Data AS MessageData, dbo.Messages.PostDate AS MessagePostDate, 
                      dbo.Channels.Name AS ChannelName, dbo.Users.Name AS UserName, dbo.Users.Uuid AS UserUuid, dbo.Channels.Uuid AS ChannelUuid
FROM         dbo.Messages INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Users ON dbo.Messages.UserId = dbo.Users.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Channels ON dbo.Messages.ChannelId = dbo.Channels.Id
```

I don't think the server hardware is a problem, I can run equivalent Rails/Grails application without any performance issue. (Dual Core, 3Gb of RAM)

A select count(*) on GlobalView returns ~270.000 lines, indexes are daily rebuilt and a explain show it uses all the clustered indexes.

I get an HTTP average response time of 8000ms, the SQL Server Management Studio shows an average CPU time for this SQL query of 866ms and an average logical IO of 7,592.03.

Database file size if ~180MB

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition, ASP.NET MVC 2 with IIS 7.5 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition with Advanced Services. They are the only things running on this server.

What can I do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the probleme,

I replaced "orderby globalView.MessagePostDate descending" by "orderby globalView.MessageId descending", because there isn't any index on MessagePostDate, and that is muuuuch better !

Thank you

Comment: well, if the query returned all ~270.000 rows, then having an index is just one part of the problem - but you are welcome, anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you got the query from SQL Server Profiler. Save the result, and pass it into the Database Engine Tuning Advisor. That might help you create additional indexes and statistics.

Comment: As I know, SQL Server Profiler is not available on the Express Edition

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity: wouldn't appending a `.ToList()` to the end of the `var messages = ...` line help?

Comment: I'm wondering that myself. Trying to enumerate after the transaction is closed seems like it would throw an error.

Comment: jwsample: well, it might just use the connection you specified at compile time and execute many-many queries as you are using the `IQueryable` you assigned in `var messages` throughout the UI on the page...

Comment: I tried this, it don't crash but don't change anything on the performances

Comment: `WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 0` : is it the query you execute?  
How many rows does it return? Shouldn't it return only the rows for a page?

Comment: The only query I execute is the one made by LINQ... It looks like the subquery returns all the view data (270.000+ records...)

Comment: @Kedare: Well, according to the samples at e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738702.aspx#_LINQ2E , "LINQ to Entities only supports Skip on ordered collections". 
...and according to this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx , they are. I guess you are using the Entity Framework? Is there a chance that you can try the same with plain LINQ to SQL?

Comment: ToList() returns everything before it, and then continues with Linq to Objects instead of Linq to Entities. While it´s an IQueryable<T> it´s an Expression Tree, and when you use ToList(), the Expression Tree is compiled to SQL and sent to the server.

Comment: @vimpyboy: I guess this is what @Kedare meant to do - instead of passing an IQueryable to the view, execute the query within the transaction. That's why I recommended appending `ToList()` to the end of the assignment. I still don't see how `Take()` is somehow left out from the expression... So the problem is really that Take()  is somehow consumed as a Linq to Objects expression.